# How do I know what port http-server is using?

Tags: angular, npm

Here I install HTTP server using `npm install http-server -g` by command prompt
but after installing it gives some relevant path but not port number, then how can I know what the port number is?

```
http://localhost:8080/index.html
```

It's throwing an error on IIS 8.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the command like 
`http-server` in the directory where the index.html is located
You can explicitly give the command which port to use with `http-server -p 8918` this will use port 8918, command without parameters defaults to 8080 or 8081 if the 8080 is occupied if I recall correctly.

You can find more info on https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server